# Rpart / Rpart.plot - what do decimals mean in node?

Tags: decision-tree, rpart

I understand the numbers followed by a "%"

But I am having trouble interpreting the numbers in decimals.

This is a type=1 plot.

Choice is Buy or Browse.

Fake data browsing an electronics store website.

Phase = first page visited, second page visited, and so on.

Is that the probability of that occurrence happening?

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmY05.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's the percentage of those who did not choose that option.